# Android official Camera2Basic sample code is out of date?

Tags: android

As I install Andoird 5.0 SDK and import the Camera2Basic sample source code.
the CameraDevice.StateListener and CameraCaptureSession.StateListener can not recgnize.

Then I check the Android developer references. found the class name changed to 
CameraDevice.StateCallback
CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback & CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.

I changed it refer to references, the error is gone, but APK still not generate.

Anyone also work on this ?

Answer (score 4):

That should be about all you can do: replace all the occurences of **CaptureListener** with **CaptureCallback**, replace all the occurences of **StateListener** with **StateCallback** and in *AndroidManifest.xml* put **<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />**. That's about all I have done and it worked.

Comment: I have make all these changes, but apk not generated even though no error reported.

Comment: Can you share that apk for me ? Can it work on Nexus 7 device ?

Comment: Is your build variant set to "debug"?  Thanks for the question, I got mine to compile and load onto device.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="21" will not run on older devices.
How can I run this sample on Android4 for example?

Comment: @ElyessAbouda The sample is designed to illustrate Android 5 camera API. Consequently, it does not work on other versions of Android.